# How do I properly validate DateTime in a CRUD situation for a model within an MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, datetime, razor, jquery-validate

I have users selecting a DateTime using a caldendar/clock popup that allows them to make a selection.  However, if they were to go in and edit the date to read something like: `6/12/201 10:36:47 AM` instead of `6/12/2012 10:36:47 AM` my Action gets past the ModelState.IsValid check and I get an error when the Controller attempts to save the object to the database (rightly so).

How do I properly validate DateTime in this situation?  (I want to prevent a user from even being able to 'submit' the form if the datetime is not properly formatted)

Note:  I currently have in place jquery.validate and typically (fields not `DateTime`) I use `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Field)` - This does not appear to do anything for my current `DateTime` fields when they are formatted inappropriately.

Comment: Do you have server side data validation as well, because just client side validation might not be enough?

Comment: You are safe to go then, because you may validate and notify users back with error/warning message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply add date client side validator for you DateTime field using snipet like that:

```
        $(element).rules('add', {
        date: true,
    });
```

where "element" is your input for DateTime field.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're importing all of the requisite validation js files? it sounds like your server validation is working OK but the client is doing nothing. I suggest reading the following post by Brad Wilson: [link](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html)